# Angular Mention Library is not working with Angular version 9

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10, angular-upgrade

I have successfully upgraded my project from Angular 9 to Angular 10.
I am using the `angular-mention` library to get the username suggestion when typing `@` keyword.

Till Angular 8 this feature was working fine but after the upgrade when I am typing `@` keyword it is not showing the list of the users.

below is the screenshot of the issue that I am facing.

[image]

as in the above picture we can see that list is coming but I am not able to see the username in the list

my component.html file looks like as follows.

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-9">
  <input
    type="text"
    spellcheck="false"
    id="userSearch"
    class="searchBox"
    [mention]="items"
    style="background-color: #ffff00"
    placeholder="Search user"
    style=""
    (keypress)="getUserDetails()"
    [(ngModel)]="searchText"
  />
</div>
```

where I am getting items from the typescript file.

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!.

Comment: what errors do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Check the items that you are passing from your component to the parent component.
Add debugger inside mention-list.ts file and check whether it's getting set or not..

Answer (score 0):

just update the library and it will work like charm i'm using the 1.4.0 and it works !!!! good luck